# Matching an attribute using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, attributes

using regex I need to match attributes that begins with a number, might contain a slash and might contain a letter as well. Because I am a beginner I don't know how to even start. These attributes are data elements from a database table. For example I would like to match all these following data:

```
54/6
66A
75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp could help to you. (https://regex101.com/r/sJ8tB6/1)

```
(^[0-9A-Za-z\/]+)

^ = start with
0-9 = any number
A-Z = any letter is uppercase
a-z = any letter in lowercase
/ = and the slash, but you need to escape this with the backslash \
+ = one or more match.
```

you can go to this site, and see the example.
https://regex101.com/r/sJ8tB6/1

Regards.